# Pyqt Custom QPolygon getting deleted: RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type ImagePolygon has been deleted

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I have a program which loads multiple images and each image has an array of polygons which are represented by a custom QGraphicsPolygon item. I load 1 image at a time with its respective polygons into two QGraphicsScene (new QGraphicsScene on each load). The problem I am encountering is that after switching between image a couple times I get the following error:
"RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type ImagePolygon has been deleted". This implementation used to work well, but I have added a lot of stuff to the program since and now I get the error.

I know that I am never loosing my references to the custom QGraphicsPolygons and the only thing that is getting deleted inside them is the polygon itself. All other membervariables stay intact. Unfortunately I have not been able to pinpoint the exact region of the code where the polygon inside the QGraphicsPolygon gets deleted and the code is too long to post here.

I have also tried to simple set a new QPolygon to the QGraphicsPolygon item each time I add it to the scene, but this gives me the same error.

Please let me know if anybody knows what could be deleting this item. Keep in my I am never loosing reference to the QGraphicsPolygonItem.

I would also appreciate if somebody knew of a good way to debug this. I am sure I could fix the error if I could find it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing I think I found the problem. Since in my implementation I delete the QGraphicsScene everytime I show a new image, I believe this was deleting the polygons as well. I don't know why this was not happening before, but I managed to fix it by first removing all items from the scene. I had to iterate through the items, because using the clear() method in the scene deletes them.